# How to use UMain in Delphi

Tags: delphi-xe

I have started to research `Delphi` and have created a project that
 includes packages. I would like to use `UMain` in one package as follows:

```
  implementation {$R *.dfm} uses UMain in 'UMain.pas';
```

But I get this error:

> [dcc32 Error] UIssue.pas(98): E2029 , or ; expected but IN
>   found

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just `uses UMain;` The `in` portion is only used in the project file.

Comment: thanks Ken White but when i uses Umain ; have error [dcc32 Error] E1026 File not found: 'UMain.dfm'

Comment: I found solution for this ,i add search path to package contain unit. Umain. thanks.

Comment: Updated grammar and formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You use the `in` notation only in the dpr project file. Inside a unit, you just reference the unit name you want to include.